# Elasticsearch sort by multiple scores

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.
We know that ES provide a score to each document using its TF/IDF algo and other calculations. This could be in range of 1-100.

Now lets suppose i have an additional score for each document, a custom calculated score, that can be in range from 1 to 1000.

I want to use this new custom score for ranking of documents but since ES score is indeterministic i.e. it can range from 1 to 100 (given number of words match, fields etc), so normalising the new custom score and adding to ES score does not work. (samples below)

Is there any solution to using other custom scores but not ignoring ES score ?

---

**Sample data**

Note : Here i just added the custom score to ES score and results are unexpected.

ES query : [anotepad.com/notes/e7t5yh](http://anotepad.com/notes/e7t5yh)

ES Results : [anotepad.com/notes/5h6dtk](http://anotepad.com/notes/5h6dtk)

What you would see in the results is that even when i searched for "32 GB iphone", i got "Apple iphone 64 GB" on top since custom score of 64 GB is way higher than that of 32 GB.

Comment: How about leveraging [`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) in order to boost the ES score depending on the given  additional score field present in your document?

Comment: I did that. but results are unexpected. Lets suppose there is doc for which ES score is very low (due to not good match), but if its custom score is very high ( around 1000) then it messes the results. What i want is to always give preference to ES score, something like sort by ES score first and then by my custom score.

Comment: Is there any way where i can push score of "not good" matches to below 1 or 0 or any integer ?. Like good matches always have score of more than 3 and bad matches always below 1. Something like that.

Comment: It'd probably help if you could show some sample data/queries/results and what you expect otherwise your question might end up being flagged as being too broad.

Comment: ES query : https://anotepad.com/notes/e7t5yh, 
ES Results : https://anotepad.com/notes/5h6dtk

What you would see in the results is that even when i searched for "32 GB iphone", i got "Apple iphone 64 GB" on top since custom score of 64 GB is way higher than that of 32 GB.

Comment: Please update your question so it's more legible.

Comment: Updated the question with sample query and data.

Comment: I would look at how the score is calculated in details and see where the problem is, meaning "how come ES thinks `iphone 64` is more relevant than `iphone 32` if I search for an iPhone 32?". You are talking about abstract notions: "not good", "bad". You are the one who defines "good" and "bad"...

Comment: This is trial and error approach, based on what you find from looking at how ES computed your scores (using `explain`). For example, to strengthen the idea that `iphone 32` is "better" than `iphone 64` I would look at adding another search to your existent search: the one based on proximity matching where you say `32` has to be "closer" to `iphone` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-relevance.html. After you add this and look at scores again, see what went well and if there are any other situations to tackle. If there are, add one more type of search.